# Determine which row updated or inserted in the sql server periodically

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to sense all the rows of some **sql server 2008** tables if any changes occur using java technology.

I have investigated some approaches like use of timestamps column , Change Tracking mechanism , Change Data Capture.

But all the above approaches need some customization in database as follows:

> 1.Timestamps column should present in each table.
>
> 2.Change tracking require primary key in each table.
>
> 3.Change Data Capture require some creation of system tables and other customizations.

I need some approach which do not require such heavy customizations in the database because database is crucial and does not allow to alter the config settings.

Can anyone help or suggest something in this regard?

Comment: how about using triggers?  Have you seen http://www.techexams.net/forums/sql-server-exams/54235-loging-data-changes-sql-server-2008-a.html

Comment: Triggers are similar to CDC's in that you need to create them and whatever dump tables you need to store the changes. As for "any changes using java technology", the best way I can see you do that is if all of your Java software uses some specific SQL login / user reserved only for them, and fetching that every time your trigger / whatever stores the information.

Comment: No, I am not allowed to write any type of triggers.
As I said I can only do light weight changes with database.No trigger and code can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The below changes can accomplish data audit

1. Create an identity column for all txn tables.
2. Fetch this identity data to the front end along with the transaction data.
3. Create history tables for all txn tables and move the original data prior to every transaction using a version ID.
4. After modification in the UI, pass the data back to database and compare the data with the existing information using SQL MERGE statement to perform the update/Insert/Delete
5. Compare the latest version available in the history table with the data in the current table using the following logic

New data Inserted - IF an Identity key exist in current table and NOT available in the latest version data of history table

WHERE C.IdentityColumn NOT IN (Select identitycolumn from History H)

Data deleted - IF an identity key exist in the latest version data of history tables AND NOT exist in the current table.

WHERE H.IdentityColumn NOT IN (Select identitycolumn from Current C)

Data updated - IF identity key exist in both current table and latest version of history table and any one column data is modified

WHERE (C.IdentityColumn = H.IdentityColumn)
AND
(
C.Col1 <> H.Col1
OR
C.Col2 <> H.Col2
OR
C.ColN <> H.ColN
)

C - Current table
H - History table

using the above logic the modified  data can be tracked in a separate audit table which can have columns like Record ID, Field Name, Old Value, New Value, Modification, Modified By, Modified Date/Time